# Is $\mathbb R^0$ a clopen set on $\mathbb R^0$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I learnt here that $\mathbb R^n$ is a clopen set on $\mathbb R^n$, and $\mathbb R^n$ is a closed set on $\mathbb R^m\forall m>n$.

Is $\mathbb R^0$ a clopen set on $\mathbb R^0$? Intuition says yes. But it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: The empty set and the whole set are always clopen, by the very definition of topology. (As the definition says, that both are open, snd as they are complements of each other, they aso are automatically both closed)

Comment: what do you mean by $R^0$?

Comment: How about tagging your question properly?

Comment: check the axiomatic definition of topology.

Comment: Doesn't matter what $\mathbb R^0$ is (although I'd imagine that would be either a space with a single point, or the empty space).  Any space $X$ is clopen in $X$.

Comment: "Intuition says yes. But it seems counter-intuitive."  How the hell does intuition seem counter-intuitive?????  Either it is your intuition or it is not your intuition.  By definition counter-intuitive is not your intuition so you are saying this is both your intuition and not your intuition.  Well, which is it?

Comment: @fleablood.  It not empty because R^0 x R^1 = R^1.  BTW, watch your language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^0$ is just a one-point space $\{p\}$. It has only two subsets (the empty set and itself) both of which are clopen in it. (in its unique topology).